# Tunnel on remote MS-windows port 443

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

I need to create a tunnel in a remote MS-windows, so the port 443 in MS-windows is redirected to a remote target on port 443.

What I'm trying to do is this, from my remote server:

```
ssh -N -R 443:remote.target:443 administrator@windows.source
```

But I get this error:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 443
```

In the windows server I installed OpenSSH.

The tunnel works if I use the 8443 port in windows, eg:

```
ssh -N -R 8443:remote.target:443 administrator@windows.source
```

But I need do do the tunnel with 443. I tried to better configure OpenSSH ("AllowTcpForwarding yes", "PermitTunnel yes" and "GatewayPorts yes" and I tried also to restart the sshd service as an administrator), but it didn't work.

Comment: Are there 3 machines involved?

Comment: Yes, there is
- one server with a service on port 443 to which I have to connect to
- my server that is used to do the tunnel
- the windows server that needs to connect to the first one and that cannot do directly

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the port is reserved. Ports below 1024 are reserved on many OSs. To use them you have to have special permission (e.g. be root user).

Try a higher port number. If this works then you know what the problem is. (Only the listening port has to be higher.)

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I need to do the tunnel on that port. I'm already connecting using the administrator account in the Windows server, maybe there is a perticular connection on OpenSSH?

Comment: Have you tested on another port? That way you will know if this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I tested  using another port and it is working. I also tried to change some OpenSSH settings, like "AllowTcpForwarding yes", "PermitTunnel yes" and "GatewayPorts yes" and I tried also to restart the sshd service as an administrator, but I didn't notice any difference. The sshd_config file is read correctly, because if I change ssh port, I have to use it to be able to connect.

Comment: OK. Then edit the question to tell us what does work, and what does not (low numbered ports).

Comment: I don't see a way to edit the question, I can only add comments under it.

Comment: Click the [edit button](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/568913/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on Windows Server 2019 where I installed "OpenSSH Server" with "Manage optional features" and configured

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
```

I'm getting the same error as you.
The ports that can be used are in the range **1001 to 65535**.
I'm still stuck on this problem. and using the command `netstat -an` did not find any program using port 443.
I tested further using the network testing tool. `.\iperf3.exe -s -p 443` on Windows Server and on client machines use the command `.\iperf3.exe -c windows.source -p 443` can be used without any problems found.

Comment: Since there is neither a solution nor a description on how to narrow it down, this should rather be a comment to the question. Or can you edit it into a (focused) answer?